# Change root directory in command prompt via batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I began programming in Java. I'm using command prompt to see my program results and everytime, when I launch command prompt I see:

```
C:\Users\Username
```

I collect all my programs inside java folder, which is inside mentioned directory and for me it would be easier to launch batch file, which will go to this directory:

```
C:\Users\Username\java
```

And from there I would be able to compile, run my programs. I was looking for some solutions via Google, but I haven't find any examples. However I tried to this on my own, so I created a batch file in C:/ , named as java.bat and wrote a code:

```
cd /d C:\Users\Username\java
```

And then made another batch file in the same directory as java.bat, named it as javastart.bat and wrote a code:

```
start c:\java.bat
```

And heres my question why it doesnt work? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start` means `establish and run a new process.`

So , batch will establish and run a new process which switches to the specified directory and then terminates since that's all the batch apparently specifies.

The easy way is to set up a shortcut to `cmd` and set the `start in` parameter (Shortcut properties/shortcut tab) to the required directory.